# Issue with the ios folder, after expo ejecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, paypal, expo

I'm trying to integrate paypal payments into my expo app, but as expo not yet supports paypal i was trying the react-native-paypal package. This requires to add some extra dependencies into the ios/android folders so i was trying to eject from expo using expo eject. Note that im running this command from a windows operating system and i also did find a way to install cocoapods. But the thing is that after running expo eject it warns me that i should do this procedure from macOS or linux to get the ios folder. How else can i get this? Thanks in advance.